# Sending emails with attachment in django

Tags: django, django-forms, attachment

I'm trying to send email with some images attached in django. Code used is this snippet : http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1063/. I don't know, why the attachment part returns me a core error.

The code. `forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from common import slugify_unique
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.contrib.admin import widgets    
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404                                   

class WorkForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name and surname', max_length=64, required = True )
    nick = forms.CharField(label='nickname', max_length=40, required = True )
    email = forms.EmailField(label='e-mail', required = True )
    image1 = forms.Field(label='sample photo', widget = forms.FileInput,    required = True )
    image2 = forms.Field(label='sample photo', widget = forms.FileInput, required = True )
    image3 = forms.Field(label='sample photo', widget = forms.FileInput, required = True )
    text = forms.CharField(label='Few words about you', widget=forms.Textarea, required = False )
```

views.py

```
from forms import WorkForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage


def work(request):
    template = 'other/work.html'                             
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WorkForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            nick = form.cleaned_data['nick']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            subject = 'Work'
            text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            image1 = request.FILES['image1']
            image2 = request.FILES['image2']
            image3 = request.FILES['image3']
            try:
                mail = EmailMessage(subject, text, ['EMAIL_ADDRESS'], [email])
                mail.attach(image1.name, attach.read(), attach.content_type)
                mail.attach(image2.name, attach.read(), attach.content_type)
                mail.attach(image3.name, attach.read(), attach.content_type)
                mail.send()
                template = 'other/mail_sent.html'
            except:
                return "Attachment error"
            return render_to_response(template, {'form':form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))   
    else:
        form = WorkForm()                              
    return render_to_response(template, {'form':form},
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And here's error site image :
http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/6027/coreerror.png
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The error traceback you've posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with the actual code - it seems to be some sort of problem with middleware (presumably when rendering the 500 error page).

However, your error is probably caused by your use of the undefined variable name `attach` in the calls to `mail.attach`. You don't have an `attach` variable - you've called the posted files `image1` etc, so you should use those names.

```
mail.attach(image1.name, image1.read(), image1.content_type)
mail.attach(image2.name, image2.read(), image2.content_type)
mail.attach(image3.name, image3.read(), image3.content_type)
```

Comment: can I use Django's send_email() method to attach files or I have to work with EmailMessage class in this case.

Comment: @chiragsoni It's better you use the EmailMessage class directly. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/core/mail/#send_mail

Comment: I would say a cleaner answer to @chiragsoni's question is that it's not possible to use send_mail(). From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/email/) - "Not all features of the EmailMessage class are available through the send_mail() and related wrapper functions. If you wish to use advanced features, such as BCC’ed recipients, file attachments, or multi-part email, you’ll need to create EmailMessage instances directly"

Answer (score 1):

### Send Mail with attachment in Django

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms


class SendMailForm(forms.Form):
    email_id = forms.EmailField()
    email_cc = forms.EmailField()
    email_bcc = forms.EmailField()
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    msg = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    attachment = forms.FileField()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import SendMailForm


# Create your views here.
def simple_send_mail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fm = SendMailForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if fm.is_valid():
            subject = fm.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = fm.cleaned_data['msg']
            from_mail = request.user.email
            print(from_mail)
            to_mail = fm.cleaned_data['email_id']
            to_cc = fm.cleaned_data['email_cc']
            to_bcc = fm.cleaned_data['email_bcc']
            print(fm.cleaned_data)
            attach = fm.cleaned_data['attachment']
            if from_mail and to_mail:
                try:
                    mail = EmailMessage(subject=subject, body=message, from_email=from_mail, to=[to_mail], bcc=[to_bcc],
                                        cc=[to_cc]
                                        )
                    mail.attach(attach.name, attach.read(), attach.content_type)
                    mail.send()
                # except Exception as ex:
                except ArithmeticError as aex:
                    print(aex.args)
                    return HttpResponse('Invalid header found')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/mail/thanks/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
    else:
        fm = SendMailForm()
    return render(request, 'mail/send_mail.html', {'fm': fm})
```

**settings.py**

```
# Email Configurations

# DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = ''
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@abc.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '************'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**send_mail.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mail</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <center><h1>Mail send from "{{request.user.email}}"</h1></center>
        {{fm.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```