# How to send an email with attachment?

Tags: python, django, excel, email

Using xlwt I have created an Excel sheet that with Django I would like to email as an attachment.

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='Report.xls'

book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = book.add_sheet("Core Listings")

book.save(response)
return response
```

I am using Django `EmailMessage` to send out emails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sending-emails-with-attachment-in-django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457906/sending-emails-with-attachment-in-django)

Comment: Did you try either the `attachments` argument to the constructor or the `attach()` method?

Comment: Yes But I am not saving that to disk, So How can I use attach()?

Comment: Use a [tmp file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=tmpfile#os.tmpfile)?

Comment: It probably supports a file-like object like you get from `StringIO`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a MimeBase object in memory from the spreadsheet data and attach that object in the attach method. The [attach method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) takes the file triplet or a MimeBase object. See [pydoc description](http://pydoc.org/2.2.3/email.MIMEBase.html) about MimeBase and [an example](https://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/01/13/send-emails-using-python/).