# how can I process to send generated pdf as attach mail in django?

Tags: django

for my homework, I need to send an attach pdf to e-mail.I have when I download I have **format error: not a pdf or damaged**.

Definition of render_to_pdf

**utils.py**

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

the generated function :

**views.py**

```
class GeneratePDF(View):
    context_object_name = 'services'
    template_name = 'pdf.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template = get_template('configuration/pdf.html')
        f=Reservation.objects.all().filter(Q(valide=True, option__in=Option.objects.all().filter(Q(code_option='GTR', 
        posseder_niveau__in=Posseder_Niveau.objects.all().filter(niveau_id = 1))))).order_by('date_du_jour_reserve')
        c = Plage_Horaire.objects.all()

        context = {
            "c":c,
            'f':f,

        }
        html= template.render(context)
        pdf = render_to_pdf('configuration/pdf.html', context)
        if pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
            filename = "emploidetemps.pdf" 
            content = "inline; filename=%s " %filename
            download = request.GET.get("download")
            if download:
                content = "attachment; filename=%s" %(filename)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
        return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

**Email function**

```
def mailjoin(request):

    GeneratePDF.as_view()
    email = EmailMessage()
    email.subject = "test"
    email.body='emploi de temps'
    email.from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    email.to = ['xxxxxxxx@gmail.com' ]
    email.attach("emploidetemps.pdf", 'application/pdf')
    email.send()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending emails with attachment in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457906/sending-emails-with-attachment-in-django)

Comment: Please consult the update question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can send email with an attachment without saving it in database, see Django [`EmailMessage.attach()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) description. To send a PDF as an attachement simply add it to an email ([as stated in similar SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457906/sending-emails-with-attachment-in-django)):

```
mail.attach('my_pdf_filename.pdf', my_pdf.read(), 'application/pdf')
```

Comment: Please Sir how can I do to recover the pdf generated. i have review my post to share my email function

Comment: @GabinTEKAM Because there a mistake in your `render_to_pdf` method. This method should return a bytes like object: `result.getvalue()` instead of HttpResponse `HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')`.

Comment: @GabinTEKAM If you send an email in your view - you do not have recover anything. Simply use the same object both in email attachment and in HttpResponse, which is returned by the view.

Comment: Thank you Sir Know i can receive an email from my application