# Django sending email with pdf

Tags: python, django

How to send an email with pdf or attachment and html using django

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

email_template =render_to_string('accounts/email.html')

send_mail=EmailMessage('Your Enrollment: ',email_template,  [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, Email] , [Email])
send_mail.attach_file('static/pdf/ENROLLMENT-PROCEDURE-2021-.pdf')
send_mail.send()
print(send_mail)
```

this is the email I received

[image]

Comment: Try `send_mail.send(fail_silently=False)` to make sure that exceptions raised while sending the message won't be quashed. More details in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects

Answer (score 0):

you can send an email with an attachment without saving it in the database, see Django EmailMessage.attach() description. To send a PDF as an attachment simply add it to an email ([Sending emails with attachment in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457906/sending-emails-with-attachment-in-django)):

```
mail.attach('my_pdf_filename.pdf', my_pdf.read(), 'application/pdf')
```

Comment: i have html template, how am i send both email and attachment in email?